# Codeigniter Upload image and insert to my folder

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter and I have a form where I can add a new item.

In this form I have a field where I can upload a image and insert to my database.

All works fine to insert into my database.

My question is, how can I add the image which I have uploaded to my folder?

**path:** `nameofproject/imagens/banner/`

Here is my controller:

```
function novo(){
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); 
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('banda', 'Banda', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('data', 'Data', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hora_inicio', 'Hora In�cio', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hora_fim', 'Hora Fim', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('morada', 'Morada', 'required'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('preco', 'Pre�o', 'required|numeric'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('aquisao_bilhetes', 'Aquisi��o de Bilhetes', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('descricao', 'Observações', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Imagem', 'required|[image/jpeg|image/png]|file_path[../../imagens/banner/]');

    if ( ! $this->input->post())
    {
        $this->load->view("concertForm");
    }
    else
    {
        $dados=$this->input->post();
        $this->load->model("Dados_model");
        $results = $this->Dados_model->insere($dados);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the manual http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html Then post your upload code

Comment: Is your question related to the CI API to deal with file uploads or are you unsure about how to "store" an uploaded file into a db ?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani:  my question how to add the image to the folder.. because to the database it works fine

Comment: You already have the answer, then (hint: look above my comment) :-)

Comment: can you help with the code?

Comment: Does that translate to "would you give me a ready-made piece of code" ? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to store a reference to your image in the database (ie: you have a column that is filename and you store: myupload.jpg in it) or do you physically want to store the image in the database?

If it's the first than you'll want to use the `$this->upload->data()` help function to grab the information about your file.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

maybe this can help your question,

**1 Initializing the Upload Class**

Like most other classes in CodeIgniter, the Upload class is initialized in your controller using the *$this->load->library* function:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```

**2 Setting Preferences**

Similar to other libraries, you'll control what is allowed to be upload based on your preferences. In the controller you built above you set the following preferences:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; //you can change this set preferences for folder upload

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

$config['max_size'] = '100';

$config['max_width'] = '1024';

$config['max_height'] = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

// Alternately you can set preferences by calling the initialize function. Useful if you auto-load the class:

$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

you can chek this   [User manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: Sorry, dude. I don't think copy-n-paste from the online manual is fair.

Comment: Why copy text that is a click away, without adding anything ? Just provide the pointer, the OP is able to read and come back with more questions if he has doubts about what's there.

Comment: ya usaha dong.. kan gw cuma ngasih ide untuk baca kalo mau gw kasih betulinnya.. give a models code and view code  biar gw tau dimana letak kesalahan code lo

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak Malaysian.